# how to sort List objects based on the object fields in Scala?

Tags: scala, list, sorting, object

I have a List of objects(for example, Student(Name: String, RollNo: Int)) and is there a way to sort them in Scala?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sortWith() function or Ordered trait to sort the List objects. check out the below link:

[Sorting a List of custom objects using sortWith function in Scala](http://clearurdoubt.com/sorting-a-list-of-custom-objects-using-sortwith-function-in-scala/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
case class Student(name: String, rollNo: Int)

val list = List(Student("bbb",1), Student("aaa",1))

val sortedList = list.sortBy(_.name)
```

or choose the `rollNo` property.